# undecimated wavelet transformation

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, discrete-wavelet-transform

[image: 1-D signal waveform]I have 20kHz sampled dc current data of 3 second (i.e signal length of 60000). I want to use undecimated wavelet transform to extract statistical features from it. But i don't know how to choose best performing mother wavelet and decomposition level. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Would you care to share some more information on your problem? What are you trying to achieve? Do you have any knowledge of the signal? Are there any specific characteristics of the signal you are interested in? And a whole lot of other things that could help you understand what the problem is if you knew nothing about it.

Comment: I added a waveform of my signal. The signal represents a fault in a system at 1s time.(in no fault case, waveform is smooth i.e is no fluctuations as seen in fault signal). My aim is to classify fault and no-fault signal.  For that i need to use undecimated wavelet transform and extract the statistical features (mean, median, maximum, minimum, spectral energy etc. ) from decomposed coefficients. but i lost the momentum of my work at what mother wavelet and decomposition level is suitable for this kind of signal.